# PHP in_array not working true

Tags: php, mysql

I have a `mysql_query` to `select *` from an `'english'` list database and `mysql_fetch_assoc` returns an  array. I try to search word `'flick'` (which actually exists in the database) by using `in_array()` if `'flick'` is found, it shouldn't be shown but it is shown. I think `in_array` function does not find the word `'flick'`.  Please look at code below:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
require 'db.php';

function spellcheck($word)
{
$output = array();
$word   = mysql_real_escape_string($word);

$words  = mysql_query("SELECT `word` FROM `english` WHERE LEFT(`word`, 1) = '" .
 substr($word, 0, 1) . "'");

 while(($words_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($words)) && (in_array($word, $words_row)==false))
  {
    similar_text($word, $words_row['word'], $percent);
    if($percent > 82)
    {
      $output[] = $words_row['word'];
    }
  }

  return (empty($output)) ? false : $output;
}

  if (isset($_GET['word']) && trim($_GET['word']) != null)
  {
    $word = $_GET['word'];
    $spellcheck = spellcheck($word);

    if ($spellcheck !== false)
    {
      echo '<pre>' . print_r($spellcheck, true) . '</pre>'; 
    } else {
      echo '<p>' . $word . ' spelled correctly, or no suggestions founds.</p>';
    }
  }
?>
<form action="" method="GET">
Check single word spelling:
<input type="text" name="word" />
<input type="submit" value="Check" /> 
</form>
```

The code returns:

```
Array (
    [0] => flick 
    [1] => flicks
)
```

But it should be:

```
 "spelled correctly, or no suggestions founds."
```

Comment: Don't use `mysql_*` functions anymore. They're deprecated for a long time and get finally removed with PHP7 in the next few months. Use PDO or mysql**i** instead.

Comment: Thanks. Are you believe the `mysql_*` is the reason of the wrong answer?

Comment: Dear @deceze, I test `mysqli_*` and sorrily the answer is the same. It means there is no deference between mysl and mysqli in my localhost xampp.

Comment: @Majid The difference is that `mysqli` will work in the future, and `mysql_query` is already producing tons of warnings in PHP 5.5.

Answer (score 2):

replace this line

```
 while(($words_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($words)) && (in_array($word, $words_row)==false))
```

with

```
 while(($words_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($words))) {
    if((in_array($word, $words_row)==false)) {
```

and at bottom close if statement

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I tried it before and it did not work. Because I believe there is no deference between your offered code and my code .

Answer (score 1):

After 2 days working on my problem I found the answer.
the mistake is in the output of the query by `mysql_fetch_assoc`. Actually it returns an associative array but every key is added a space (' ') after that.
So, the result is not like `abcdefg`. The result is like `a b c d e f g`. It means when I search a special word in the associative array, the `in_array()` function returns false. Because for example the word `'flick'` is not equal to `'flick '` and there is a space after the keys in array. I used `trim()` function and solved my problem:

```
while ($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
  {
    foreach($rows as $key)
    {
      $key = trim($key);
      $array[] = $key; 
    } 
  }
    if (in_array($word, $array))
    {
      echo "The word is spelled correctly";
    } else {
      foreach($array as $key)
      {
        similar_text($word, $key, $percent);
        if ($percent > 82)
        {
          $output[] = $key;  
        }
      }      
    }
```

tank you for your paying attention to my answer.

Comment: I forgot to say my database is created by using a simple english words list. After replacing it with a `.csv` format list by importing to my database and using    `while(($words_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($words))) {
        if((in_array($word, $words_row)==false)) {` my broblem was solved.